# Python 3.2 _thread module produces no output using Ubuntu 12.04, but works fine with windows 7

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I'm hoping that someone has a quick and easy solution to this issue that I'm facing.  I'm working through chapter 5 of the 4th edition of the Programming Python book by Mark Lutz and I'm having some troubles beginning on page 189.  Basically, there is a very simple example:

```
import _thread
def action(i):
    print(i ** 32)

_thread.start_new_thread(action, (2, ))
```

For some reason, this script will not produce any output on my pc running Ubuntu 12.04, but will on my windows 7 machine.  The output when run from the terminal is:

```
un@homepc:~/Desktop/pp$ python3.2 thread1.py
un@homepc:~/Desktop/pp$
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert of threads but this is most likely the problem:

When running this code, Python has nothing to do after the last line;so it exits forcefully ending the thread (whether it completed or not).
Depending on how the threads run, the thread may complete or it may not. (unreliable behaviour)

main thread pseudo-code instruction:

create the new thread

new thread:

action(2)

main thread next instruction:

program ended;exit

Fixed code:

```
import _thread
def action(i):
    print(i ** 32)
    action_lock.release() #Now Python will exit

#locks are a part of threaded programming; if you don't know what it is, you can google it.
action_lock = _thread.allocate_lock() #set a lock for the action function thread
action_lock.acquire() #Acquire the lock
_thread.start_new_thread(action, (2, ))
action_lock.acquire()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I appreciate it.  If I add another line to the end, such as print("completed"), that will print, but still no other output.  I'm still baffled by the fact that this program functions properly in Windows 7, but not in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: oh the fixed code wouldn't work!! I forgot to paste the correct code!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramchandra for pointing me in the right direction.  The problem was that the program was ending and killing the threads.  If I run this:

```
import time, _thread

def print_t(name, delay):
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(delay)
            print(name)
        except: pass

_thread.start_new_thread(print_t, ("First Thread", 1,))
_thread.start_new_thread(print_t, ("Second Thread", 2,))

while True:
    try: pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ending main program")
        break
```

... then the program executes as planned.  I don't have an answer as to why the code in the original post worked on windows 7, but not on ubuntu 12.04.  Oh well.  Hope this helps someone, sometime.

Comment: this is not the correct solution - use a lock as illustrated in my answer